# Use regex to validate angular expressions in a paragraph input

Tags: regex, string

I have a difficult user-input validation question (or at least it's difficult for me).  I'm trying to make sure users are inputting a pre-defined subset of allowed Angular expressions if they try to add angular to their input at all.

I'm currently using http://www.regexpal.com/ (the actual implementation is in an HTML webpage using javascript) to test my expression and the two following cases:

VALID

```
Any text, punctuation (except double-{), or numb3r5 {{model.variable|phone}} is valid
Any text, punctuation (except double-{), or numb3r5 {{model.variable}} is valid.
Stick with the format {{model.variable|zipcode}} and we remain valid.
```

INVALID

```
Any text, punctuation (except double-{), or numb3r5 {{model.variable|phone}} is valid
Any text, punctuation (except double-{), or numb3r5 {{model.variable}} is valid.
Any deviation from the format, e.g. {{model.variable|custom}} makes the entire input invalid.
```

I figured out the regex to identify the three angular blocks and un-match the "custom" one...

```
{{model\.[^}|]+(\|((ein)|(phone)|(zipcode)|(currency:'':0)){1})?}}
```

... but I can't get it to enforce that regex.  I tried lots of variations on lookaheads, and this is what I think I need, but it doesn't match the valid input, so obviously I'm off.

```
^(((.(?!({{)|(}})))*({{model\.[^}|]+(\|((ein)|(phone)|(zipcode)|(currency:'':0)){1})?}}))?)+$
```

Does anyone out there know how I might validate this input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nicely composed question. You described the problem and what you have tried.

Using Lookaheads is one solution but you may end up consuming the text for other purposes, so normal groups work fine here.

I would suggest:`^((?:^|[^\r\n\{]*)(?:\{(?:[^{]|$)|(?:\{{2}model\.variable(?:\|(?:(ein)|(phone)|(zipcode)|(currency:'':0)))?\}{2}|$)))+$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZhFBwa/3))

Be aware that visibly empty strings can pass this regex. I would do a `.trim().length` check if that is an issue. I didn't think it was appropriate to add more bloat to this regex.

```
^                         # Anchors to beginning of string or line, 
                            # depending on multinline flag 
(                         # Opens capturing group 1 
  (?:                     # Opens noncapturing group
    ^                     # Anchors to the beginning of string or line
  |                       # or
    [^\r\n\{]*            # Any character but carriage return, new line, {, one or more times 
  )                       # Closes noncapturing group 
  (?:                     # Opens noncapturing group
    \{                    # Literal { 
    (?:                   # Opens noncapturing group 
      [^{]                # Any character but {
                            # to filter {{'ss
    |                     # or
      $                   # End of string or line 
    )                     # Closes noncapturing group 
  |                       # or 
    (?:                   # Opens noncapturing group 
      \{{2}               # {, twice 
      model\.variable     # model.variable 
      (?:                 # Opens noncapturing group 
        \|                # Literal | 
        (?:               # Opens noncapturing group 
          (ein)           # ein as capturing group 2 
        |                 # or 
          (phone)         # phone as capturing group 3
        |                 # or
          (zipcode)       # zipcode as capturing group 4
        |                 # or 
          (currency:'':0) # currency as capturing group 5
        )                 # closes non-capturing group 
      )?                  # closes non-capturing group, iternates 0 or 1 times
      \}{2}               # }, twice 
    |                     # or
      $                   # end of string or line, dependong on multiline 
    )                     # 
  )                       # 
)+                        # 
$                         #
```

> Per: ***I'm going to run with this and see if I can get it to ignore the newlines/carriage returns when building the overall match for the entire input.***

`^((?:^|[^{]+)(?:\{(?:[^{]|$)|(?:\{{2}model\.variable(?:\|(?:(ein)|(phone)|(zipcode)|(currency:'':0)))?\}{2}|$)))+$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZhFBwa/4))

I only needed to remove the single `\r\n` and remove the multiline flag.

Comment: Nice job commenting the regex! If I were going to use a regex that complicated in production code, I'd probably leave it commented like that since regex are notoriously difficult to read/debug once they reach any complexity.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelL. Yeah, truth is, I get knee-deep in **my own** expressions sometimes and can't tell one `)` from another. So glad for `\x` (freespacing) for the big ones.

Comment: Very cool.  I like the use of the non-capturing groups to kick out useless junk from the match results.  I'm going to run with this and see if I can get it to ignore the newlines/carriage returns when building the overall match for the entire input (I apologize, it's my mistake -- I said "paragraph input" when I meant "input which contains one or more paragraphs").  Thank you!  Also, no worries about the empty text -- in my app, users can type whatever insanity they want to spoof the spacing in print format, so long as any Angular is valid.

Comment: @KieronAlsmith I hope you got it, and encourage you to try. If you didn't get it, I pasted a solution at the bottom of the answer.